# Is it possible to disable 'minify-cation' with Minify?

Tags: php, debugging, minify

Within a ZF project I'm using Minify lib to merge and minify my js, since it's an old project, I didn't wrote a view helper to handle minify and there were no way to manage this with ZF.

But well it's difficult to debug online because of the obfuscation.

i'd like to know if it's possible to disable compression, obfuscation or whatever, and just use minify to merge scripts into a single file.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [debug mode](http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/Debugging#Javascript/CSS_Problems). If you can't add `&debug` to the URLs directly, you could temporarily add `$_GET['debug'] = '1';` to your /min/config.php file in your development environment.